# How to generate a random binary image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I know that a binary image is matrix with 0 and 1 values. If I generate a matrix with numpy having 0 and 1 elements and then I use pillow library from python to read the image from the numpy array, the image is black. Why this is happen?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size=(512,512))
img =  Image.fromarray(matrix)
img.save(test.png)
```

Comment: By way of explanation, your `matrix` is probably of type `uint32` - because you didn't specify the `dtype` when creating it - which means it uses 4 bytes per pixel rather than the 1-bit you intended. Which means that black is represented by `0` and white is represented by `4,294,967,295`, so your values of `0` and `1` are all going to look pretty black on that range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a single bit PNG image. `cv2` and `PIL.Image` both support this type of images.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy
# boolean matrix
matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size=(512,512)).astype(bool)
img =  Image.fromarray(matrix)
img.save("test.png", bits=1,optimize=True)
```

Comment: Your answer works correctly, but it might be worth noting that you are creating an array at least 8x bigger in terms of RAM usage and taking around 6-7x longer than necessary in terms of time and then reducing it afterwards, with `.astype()` rather than creating it with the intended type up-front... `matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size=(512,512), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention that, but then didn't. Tried to keep it similar to the OP's question. Also, I see that `numpy.random.choice` generates float64 and then converts to bool, so I guess it would have more or less same implications